# Creating script for automated data form that logs data in other sheet tab

Tags: google-apps-script

I am looking for a script that will automatically take the entered/submitted data from a form i have created and transfer the data entered to another tab named "database" to essentially log the data. once the data is submitted, the form clears and then transferred to a database tab. I have a section in my entry form to where you can select multiple lines of data that auto populate the price of each item based on the quantity selected. I want a way that if multiple lines (items) are entered, it adds a new line with the item along with the quantity and price to the corresponding column in the database tab. So if an entry form had data/items entered from column B21-B29, it would just add new rows in the database tab in column I with each item listed below one another along with the corresponding quantity and price. so for one data form entry everything in the database tab would be on the same line except if there were multiple items entered. Here is my script currently have along with a link to my sheet. please help!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jhViptzo4DItrOn2GBi2wD8ICBwrw3c9PCh_B_3WsE4/edit?usp=sharing

```
function submitData() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var datasheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Database');
 var blankRow=datasheet.getLastRow()+1;
datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 1).setValue(sheet.getRange("B4").getValue());
datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 2).setValue(sheet.getRange("B6").getValue());
datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 3).setValue(sheet.getRange("B8").getValue());
datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 4).setValue(sheet.getRange("B10").getValue());
datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 5).setValue(sheet.getRange("B12").getValue());
datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 6).setValue(sheet.getRange("B14").getValue());
datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 7).setValue(sheet.getRange("B16").getValue());
datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 8).setValue(sheet.getRange("B18").getValue());
datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 9).setValue(sheet.getRange("B21").getValue());
datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 9).setValue(sheet.getRange("B22").getValue());
datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 9).setValue(sheet.getRange("B23").getValue());
datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 10).setValue(sheet.getRange("C21").getValue());
datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 10).setValue(sheet.getRange("C22").getValue());
datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 10).setValue(sheet.getRange("C23").getValue());
datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 11).setValue(sheet.getRange("D21").getValue());
datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 11).setValue(sheet.getRange("D22").getValue());
datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 11).setValue(sheet.getRange("D23").getValue());

sheet.getRange("B4").clear();
sheet.getRange("B6").clear();
sheet.getRange("B8").clear();
sheet.getRange("B10").clear();
sheet.getRange("B12").clear();
sheet.getRange("B14").clear();
sheet.getRange("B16").clear();
sheet.getRange("B18").clear();
sheet.getRange("B21:C50").clear();
}
```

Comment: You are only storing 3 of you last nine values.  Perhaps you wish to rethink that

Comment: Have you tried the suggested solution?

Answer (score 1):

It can be something like this:

```
function submitData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // get order info and list of items from the form sheet
  var form_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Inventory Order Form');
  var data = form_sheet.getRange('B3:D33').getValues();
  var order_info = [
      data[ 1][0], // Order Date
      data[ 3][0], // Store Requested By 
      data[ 5][0], // Urgent Request
      data[ 7][0], // Store Receiver Name 
      data[ 9][0], // Store Receiver Phone 
      data[11][0], // Market
      data[13][0], // Store Name 
      data[15][0], // Store Address
    ];
  var items = data.slice(18).filter(e => e[0] != ''); // Item, Quantity, Total Price

  // append items to the database sheet
  var database_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Database');
  items.forEach(item => database_sheet.appendRow([...order_info, ...item]));

  // clear the form
  var ranges = ['B4','B6','B8','B10','B12','B14','B16','B18','B21:D33'];
  form_sheet.getRangeList(ranges).clear();
}
```